# Efficient reduced SVD on GPU (Python)

Tags: pytorch, scipy, gpu, svd, jax

I want to perform a Singular Value Decomposition on an NxN matrix (N ~ 1000 but could also get larger) where I only care about the ~N biggest singular values.

The fastest way I found to do this is using scipy.sparse.linalg.svds. I also tried JAX, which seems to only have methods for computing the entire SVD, and is therefore slower. I also tried torch.linalg.svd (with gpu) with full_matrices=True/False, but it was still slower than scipy.

How can I efficiently compute reduced SVDs on GPU?

Answer (score 0):

JAX doesn't have a direct equivalent of `scipy.sparse.linalg.svds`, but it does have an experimental lobpcg eigenvalue solver that can compute related quantities. For example:

```py
import numpy as np
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax.experimental.sparse.linalg import lobpcg_standard

N = 100
m = 5

rng = np.random.default_rng(0)
A = jnp.array(rng.normal(size=(N, N)))

u, s, vt = jnp.linalg.svd(A)
print(s[:m])
# [19.603386 18.822197 18.222559 17.918581 17.71023 ]

# Note: LOBPCG works for hermitian operators
AAT = lambda x: A @ A.T @ x
initial = rng.normal(size=(N, m))
eigenvals, *rest = lobpcg_standard(AAT, initial, m=100, tol=1E-6)

# Eigenvalues of A.AT are the square of the singular values of A
singular_vals = jnp.sqrt(eigenvals)
print(singular_vals)
# [19.603376 18.822199 18.222528 17.918453 17.710228]
```